# subprocess popen not executing command, return code 1, network namespace

Tags: python, networking, network-programming, subprocess

I'm trying to use the **Popen** command from the **subprocess** module to create a network namespace. There is a difference in the output I see from the interpreter and the output I see when my program is run through the GUI (via a lighthttpd app).

Here's the simplified function:

```
import subprocess
from pyroute2 import netns
def addNamespace(namespace):
    setNs = "ip netns add %s"%(namespace)
    print(setNs)
    proc = subprocess.Popen(setNs.split(' '))
    ret = proc.communicate()
    print("Return Code:%d STDOUT/STDERR:%s"%(proc.returncode, str(ret)))
    print(netns.listnetns())
```

When I run this code `>>> addNamespace("b0ns")` from the python interpreter, I get:

```
ip netns add b0ns
Return Code:0 STDOUT/STDERR:(None, None)
['b0ns']
```

However, when I run the same function from the program, I get:

```
ip netns add b0ns
Return Code:1 STDOUT/STDERR:(None, None)
['']
```

The **return code here is 1** and the namespace does not get added. What could be the cause for it not executing successfully? Root privileges? I tried executing the command with adding a *`sudo`* before `ip netns add..` but that didn't work.

I tried giving the `shell=True` argument in the program and got a `return code = 255.`

I've tried using the **netns** module to directly create a namespace using `netns.create()` but I receive a `OSError:mount rundir failed`

**System details: Python 2.7.5 CentOS 7.2**

**EDIT**:
I added the function to a simple test.py file and ran it - it worked ok. There is only a problem when the function is invoked through my GUI based application.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not added much details on how you are executing your program from command line interface, so I am making a guess.

Try using:

`sudo python <programname.py>`

`ip netns add NetworkName`   required root access

so you shall have to provide root accesses to your program while executing.

Why its working from interactive shell!!! Well I guess you must have opened your interactive shell by typing something like following:

`sudo python`

Cheers!!

```
import subprocess
from time import sleep
from pyroute2 import netns
def addNamespace(namespace):
    setNs = "ip netns add %s"%(namespace)
    print(setNs)
    proc = subprocess.Popen(setNs.split(' '))
    ret = proc.communicate()
    print("Return Code:%d STDOUT/STDERR:%s"%(proc.returncode, str(ret)))
    print(netns.listnetns())


addNamespace('b2ns')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    addNamespace('b3ns')
    sleep(3)
```

Giving me:

```
pradeep@localVM:~$ sudo python add_network.py
ip netns add b2ns
Return Code:0 STDOUT/STDERR:(None, None)
['b2ns', 'b1ns', 'b0ns']
ip netns add b3ns
Return Code:0 STDOUT/STDERR:(None, None)
['b3ns', 'b2ns', 'b1ns', 'b0ns']
```

Note: `'b1ns', 'b0ns'` added with previous runs

Comment: Yea, so if I run it through a regular program the way you did, it works for me too. However, this code in my application is being invoked through a `lighthttpd` process. The real concern is, why is the return code for the subprocess set to 1? Is there a way I can debug why this specific command is not working?

Comment: what kind of permission does `lighthttpd` have on your machine